# Why performSegueWithIdentifier creates always a new instance?

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue

I have 3 view controller: `containerViewController`, `questionViewController`, `answerViewController`.

[image]

How can I swap question and answer, without to create a new instance from the view controllers? So if one is created, use that one.

Usually I swap between them like this:

```
containerViewController!.performSegueWithIdentifier("question", sender:self)
```

but this always creates a new instance.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want it to create a new instance? While it's a wasteful way of doing things, it's pretty standard behaviour and UIKit will clean up after itself to keep memory usage down

Comment: not so important, but on `question` **Table** `ViewController` what you do not see on right side on picture, I need to do some cleanup and `deinit` of `questionTableViewController` not get called, do you know why?

Comment: If `deinit` is not being called, it's very likely because you're holding onto a strong reference to the ViewController somewhere. There are also better places to tidy up your viewController, such as `viewWillDisappear`

Comment: @chedabob an array was holding reference, not `deinit` get called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it always will create a new instance. have no doubt for that. Because that command equal to create a new object and push it (or present it).

there's a lot of way to walkthrough it. In my case, i usually create questionViewController with an button, and by that button, it will present answerViewController. And answerViewController will have a button to dismiss. I think you can try it.

Comment: I need to do it programmatically, and also important to get back the same `questionViewController` pressing `back`

Comment: yes. using my way, and us "back" button to dismiss the answerViewController and you can back to exactly same questionViewController.

Comment: ahh, ok, so pressing `back` should not call `performSegueWithIdentifier` but  should remove `answerViewController` from container